# TURBO C++: Unable to open include file stdio.h

Tags: c

I am trying to compile a simple C program using `TUrbo C++ 3.2.` But getting the following error: `Unable to open include file 'STDIO.h'`

I do have these files in INCLUDE library.

Comment: use gcc instead, problem solved (among numerous others). Oh, and you should try `stdio.h` instead, note the lower case

Comment: Maybe try a compiler that hasn't been obsolete for 15 years.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Cant help you if you dont post your code. Check if you use `#include <cstdio>` (not `#include "cstdio"` or `#include <cstdio.h>` or `#include "cstdio.h"`.

`#include <cstdio>` will always work.

Comment: If it's a 'c' program, it should be '#include <stdio.h>'.

Comment: but he uses a c++ compiler as he stated in the title... I would assume the tag is wrong.